# NativeScript command to keep screen always on

Tags: nativescript

I am developing an app by NativeScript (+vue),
How can I force Android to keep the screen on, while the app is running and focused?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use [nativescript-insomnia](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-insomnia) plugin for the same.

**Install**

```
tns plugin add nativescript-insomnia
```

**Keep awake**

```
insomnia.keepAwake().then(function() {
  console.log("Insomnia is active");
});
```

Comment: Does this also work on a nativescript app for iOS? Documentation seems to make not difference between iOS and Android.